# How to center a WPF app on screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, screen-positioning

I want to center my WPF app on startup on the primary screen. I know I have to set myWindow.Left and myWindow.Top, but where do I get the values?

I found `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen`, which is apparently not WPF. Is there a WPF alternative that gives me the screen resolution or something like that?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Put this in your window constructor

```
WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
```

> .NET FrameworkSupported in: 4, 3.5,
>   3.0
>
> .NET Framework Client ProfileSupported
>   in: 4, 3.5 SP1

Comment: Worked for me (.NET 4) and I also like `WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner` for some child windows

Comment: The default is `Manual`. Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 200):

**xaml**

```
<Window ... WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">...
```

Comment: Added to <Window> tag and Works Perfectly :)

Answer (score 49):

You can still use the Screen class from a WPF app.  You just need to reference the System.Windows.Forms assembly from your application.  Once you've done that, (and referenced System.Drawing for the example below):

```
Rectangle workingArea = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
```

...works just fine.

Have you considered setting your main window property WindowStartupLocation to CenterScreen?

Comment: I was looking for WindowStartupLocation; knew I had seen that before, very useful!

Comment: @Michael Petrotta Thanks.  I should look at the properties more often.

Answer (score 8):

What about the SystemParameters class in PresentationFramework? It has a [WorkArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.workarea.aspx) property that seems to be what you are looking for.

But, why won't setting the Window.WindowStartupLocation work? CenterScreen is one of the enum values. Do you have to tweak the centering?

Comment: Great find :) The problem with center screen for me at least is, my Log in window is small and if user is clickign around while app is opening it often gets unnoticed and goes into the background. But if i can open it on the primary display in the center it works fine. note: most users have 4+ screens

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to reference the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly from your application. Instead, you can use `System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea`. This is equivalent to the `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea`!

Answer (score 4):

```
var window = new MyWindow();
```

for center of the screen use:

```
window.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
```

for center of the parent window use:

```
window.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to put it in the WPF code.

In `[WindowName].xaml` file:

```
<Window x:Class=...
...
WindowStartupLocation ="CenterScreen">
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no WPF equivalent. `System.Windows.Forms.Screen` is still part of the .NET framework and can be used from WPF though.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254197/how-can-i-get-the-active-screen-dimensions/254241#254241) for more details, but you can use the calls relating to screens by using the [`WindowInteropHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.aspx) class to wrap your WPF control.

Answer (score -1):

You have property in window `WindowStartupLocation`.

Choose `CenterScreen`.

Please refer to the below image for more info.
[image]