# How can I get a screen resolution of Device (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

How can I get a screen resolution of Device from settings (Windows Phone) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get screen size on Windows Phone 7 Series?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596732/how-to-get-screen-size-on-windows-phone-7-series)

Comment: What do you need it for? The resolution is the same.

Comment: It is now, but there will be more possible resolutions after next system update so it may be a good reason of that kind of questions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
public void GetScreenResolution()  
{  
     string ScreenWidth = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth.ToString();  
     string ScreenHeight = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight.ToString();  
     MessageBox.Show(ScreenWidth + "*" + ScreenHeight);  
}
```

Comment: It works of course (doing it the same way for my DeviceInfo app) but don't forget that if using SDK 7.1 (to support 7.x devices) it will result in wrong values when running on WP8.

Comment: On my Lumia 925 with WP8.1, it returns 480x800, while the specs sites out there claim the resolution is 768x1280. Something is off here.

Answer (score 6):

This may be a better way to know what screen resolution is your app running on.

```
if(App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 100)
{
  // WVGA
}
else if (App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 160)
{
  // WXGA
}
else if (App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 150)
{
  // 720p
}
```

Source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: And what if MS adds another scalefactor for FullHD for example ? downvote for hardcode

Comment: This is directly from Microsoft website linked above. Of course, if new resolutions/scale factors are added, then you add another conditional in the code above. Do you think there is a way around? Don't down-vote for no reason.

Comment: I would like to see your solution to this

Answer (score 1):

That solution will work on WP7.x **and** WP8 devices:
http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.co.at/2013/04/detect-screen-resolution-for-windows.html

Comment: Seems ok, but, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14018398/1130789, it will fail when Microsoft adds another display resolution! Especially since there is no exception handling if none of the scale factors matches. So at least add an default section to your switch condition.

Answer (score 1):

This actually requires a combination of [@Dmitriy Reznik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/838302/dmitriy-reznik) and [@Paras Wadehra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1621383/paras-wadehra)'s answers, as the dimensions exposed by `Host.Content` are the *unscaled* dimensions.

```
var content = App.Current.Host.Content;

var screenResolution = new Size(
    content.ActualWidth*content.ScaleFactor/100,
    content.ActualHeight*content.ScaleFactor/100);
```

Comment: Another way to know display scale is:

    `DisplayProperties.LogicalDpi / 96.0f`