# How to get screen size in Panorama control of Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, screen, screen-size

How to programatically get an actual screen size (width and height) in Windows Phone? Normally I would use the following: [How to get screen size on Windows Phone 7 Series](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4389414/2107354)

But Panorama control is a bit tricky, since the above code gives a **PanoramaItem** width and height (**not Panorama** width and height).

I have the following code that creates popup:

```
 modalPopup = new Popup();
 modalPopup.Child = new ModalWait() { MaxWidth = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth };
 modalPopup.IsOpen = true;
```

As I result a popup is created a width of PanoramaItem, which is not a total width of a phone screen. There's a right margin which is not covered with the popup. See the  screenshot below:

[image: wp screensize problem]

Any ideas how to overcome this right margin and get the actual phone screen size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MaxWidth` property does not set an element's width. It gets/sets the maximum width constraint of that element. You want to use the `Width` property instead.

The code you showed `Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth` will give you the correct screen width, not just the panorama item's width.