# How to reset height and re-center a WPF form at runtime?

Tags: wpf, runtime, height, code-behind

I try to reset the height of my form in its Loaded event but the position of the form is not centered screen anymore.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var manualHeight = 0
        + this.MessageRow.ActualHeight
        + this.ButtonsRow.ActualHeight
    ;
    this.Height = manualHeight;

    //What to do to re-center the form?
}
```

Please help if you know how to. Great thanks!

Nam.

**[Edit]**

I re-note the answer here thanks to `xandy` help.

```
var screenHeight += System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
window.Top = (screenHeight - manualHeight) / 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manually set the window y position to:

window.Top = (screenHeight - manualHeight) / 2;

where you can have the screenHeight [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254197/how-can-i-get-the-active-screen-dimensions).