# WPF window size

Tags: wpf

I am creating a Notepad like application in WPF. I want to set the window form height and width according to screen size . How can i get Screen height and width ?

Comment: True. Shouldn't assume SO to be an auto-answer-machine that saves on searching the net.

Comment: If you want the window to fit the screen size, why not just maximize it?

Comment: Google redirected me to here as the first choice ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [System.Windows.SystemParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.aspx)

You have properties like

- `PrimaryScreenWidth`
- `PrimaryScreenHeight`
- `VirtualScreenHeight`
- `VirtualScreenWidth`
- `WorkArea`

etc.

This question might help as well: [How can I get the active screen dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254197/how-can-i-get-the-active-screen-dimensions)

Answer (score 13):

Just bind `SystemParameters` properties to your window properties.

```
<Window x:Class="YourWindow"
    Height="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WorkArea}, Path=Height}" 
    Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WorkArea}, Path=Width}">
```

Comment: SystemParameters offers resource keys for all its properties. It is better to use DynamicResource instead of bindings.

Comment: This is not working here. "SystemParameters is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) Project." A shame :|