# Resolution of the current monitor

Tags: c#, winforms

**How does one get the screen resolution of the current monitor?**  By "current monitor", I mean the one that the application starts on.

The reason I ask this is because I have two monitors, the secondary monitor is 1280x1024 and the primary is 1680x1050. The application, when it starts, stupidly sets its own height and width based on the *primary* monitor resolution.  When the application launches on the secondary monitor, it overflows the resolution, which looks strange.

I know I could change/remove the code that sets the application's height/width, but I am also curious how one determines which monitor the application is showing on.

For what it's worth, I am not a proponent of applications that set their own height/width.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254197/how-can-i-get-the-active-screen-dimensions

Comment: Which toolkit are you using? WPF or Windows Forms or something else?

Comment: @MatthewWalton WinForms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Screen.FromControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.fromcontrol.aspx):

```
Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds
```

where `this` is the `Form` that you want to retrieve the `Screen` information for.