# Get Size/Location of Primary Monitor

Tags: c#, wpf, pinvoke

I need to be able to access the working area of the primary monitor using C# in WPF. I am looking for a solution that does *not* utilize the System.Windows.Forms namespace. I assume that this would require some sort of wrapper around a Win32 call.

Edit: Forgot to mention that I also need to get left/top of the primary monitor.

Comment: You can use WMI. What's wrong with System.Windows.Forms though?

Comment: Specifically the second answer on that question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/744306/781792

Comment: @ByteBlast: I don't want to use System.Windows.Forms because that would require loading a 400KB+ dll.

Comment: @ByteBlast: How would I use WMI?

Comment: It is a very common myth that loading a .NET assembly means that you are reading the file.  .NET is **much** more sophisticated than that.  With ample help from the operating system, Windows is a demand-paged virtual memory operating system.  Reading an introductory book about operating system design is important for every programmer.

Comment: @HansPassant: Does this also apply for a cold start?

Comment: Erm, no, that's not a myth.  I never once heard anybody claim that the size of the file had anything to do with the cold-start time :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the height and width of the primary screen you can use `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth` and `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight` which are in the `PresentationFramework` library.