# Winform size and location of winform on screen regardless of resolution

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, screen-resolution

I have a winform (c#, let's say 250px by 250px) that needs to stay in one location on the screen regardless of screen resolution i.e 800x600, 1920x1080 etc.  The Winform itself contains only one element - a picturebox so what's inside really doesn't matter (no need to worry about fonts, etc.).  I just need it to stick in one place on the screen from one monitor to another.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Care to comment for -1?

Comment: Do you want it to appear always on the same location after application start? Or do you want it to stay there, so that you cannot move the window?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @azt I know how to fix it's location on start up by setting pixels.  But that has to change when the resolution changes...no?

Comment: @steve thanks but as far as I can tell your reference doesn't apply to the question at hand.  I need it to be on a fix location on top of an image.

Comment: Form.StartPosition = Manual, then set the Location property with the coordinates where do you want your form to appear

Comment: So your desired position is a function of the screen size, e.g. 20% of screen with from left and 30% of screen height from top?

Comment: @azt yes. % would work.  Can I give `location` percentage?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use one of these?
1) WindowsState = Maximized (then you dont worry, it always takes whole screen)
2) StartPosition = CenterScreen (then it always shows as centered), or CenterParent to center within parent form
3) Location = in this case you would have to do some math to get screen size, your form size than based on that center it but I dont see point of using this considering that StartPosition does it already for you.
Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not trying to center it.  It has to be fixed on top of and image in some x,y coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so in order to get the window at a fixed location given in % of the screen size, you need the screen size (e.g. using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/254241/2606322)), compute the desired position, and set it as the window-location. 
Since you need to do it at startup, you could do it before you show the window, or maybe best inside a Frame.Loaded event handler.