# C# Change form size on drag and drop

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I would like to know if it is possible to change the size of the form when it is moved?

What I want to accomplish with this, is that when a user moves the form between 2 different screens the form should change its size to fit the new screen.

I tried with the DragDrop action for the Form but didn't work.

Please help!

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254197/how-can-i-get-the-active-screen-dimensions then you should be able to set the form dimensions to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check if Move method can help you ?

```
    private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this.Left.ToString());
    }
```

The example above prompt the left position of your form, so you can check the current position of your Form and try to resize it if necessary.

Comment: Thank you Skary, that was exactly what I was looking for, and I don't know how I didn't try with that method hahahahaha thanks!!!!