# Get distance from control to bottom of screen

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF I'm trying find the distance from my control to the bottom of the screen. I can get the position of the control using `.PointToScreen()` but I'm having trouble finding the distance from that point to the bottom of the screen.

I've tried using `SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height`, `SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight`, and `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight`.
All of these receive a value less than the Y postion of my control probably because the scaling is at 175%. I also have a second screen that is scaled at 100%.

I would prefer a solution that uses the screen references by the `PointToScreen`. I also looked at `System.Windows.Forms.Screen`, but would prefer a WPF solution if possible.

Comment: also, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1927540/366064

Comment: OK I found a useful answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36920187/7182460